# paperclip image broken in rails 3.1rc4

Tags: plugins, paperclip, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I am using rails 3.1rc4 with paperclip and i cannot upload any image file with. I keep getting this error
Image D:/Users/MOBILE/AppData/Local/Temp/stream20110612-3872-y7hmme-0.jpg is not recognized by the 'identify' command. I have imagemagic installed. But it works in <= rails 3.0.8rc4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if this will adress your specific issue but I found this and maybe its related:

https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/issues/481

It states:
The paperclip:refresh:metadata rake task fails with Rails 3.1 as ActiveRecord no longer supports instance.save(false) - you must now use instance.save(:validate => false) instead.

Comment: thanks but i had to download rails installer 2.0 which has ruby 1.9.2 and it works fine

Answer (score 2):

I'm on Mac and I had the exact same problem after I updated to Mac OS Lion,
in order to fix this error I had to reinstall imagemagick

This might help other Mac OS Lion users:

First make sure to download the latest XCode from the app store (4.1 atm I believe, it's free)

Using [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/):

```
brew uninstall imagemagick
brew update
```

if you get any errors, clean up files ending in .a or .la with "brew doctor",
then just do

```
brew install imagemagick
```

If you are using [MacPorts](https://www.macports.org/) do:

```
port uninstall imagemagick
port selfupdate
port install imagemagick
```